# ContextMenu inside ContextMenu in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to get the following behavior: 
When I right-click on **My button** it should open a window with buttons. When I right-click **Button 1.2**, I want to open another window with another kind of buttons.

[image]

**NOTE**: The style of **Button 2.x** is different than on the **Button 1.x**,

I've tried to make this work using `ContextMenus`, but when I right click on **Button 1.x** nothing happens. Is it impossible to use nested `ContextMenus`? Are there any other possibilities?

Here is an example:

```
<Button Content="Hello">
  <Button.ContextMenu>
      <ContextMenu>
          <MenuItem/>
          <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
              <Style>
                  <Setter Property="MenuItem.Template">
                      <Setter.Value>
                          <ControlTemplate>
                              <Button Content="Level 1">
                                  <Button.ContextMenu>
                                      <ContextMenu>
                                          <MenuItem />
                                          <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                                              <Style>
                                                  <Setter Property="MenuItem.Template">
                                                      <Setter.Value>
                                                          <ControlTemplate>
                                                              <Button Content="Level 2" />
                                                          </ControlTemplate>
                                                      </Setter.Value>
                                                  </Setter>
                                              </Style>
                                          </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                                      </ContextMenu>
                                  </Button.ContextMenu>
                              </Button>
                          </ControlTemplate>
                      </Setter.Value>
                  </Setter>
              </Style>
          </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
      </ContextMenu>
  </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Comment: To make it possible you need to use popup to show on right click. bind the popup on where do you click and open the next popup. keep the popup open until you lose focus or click outside is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Much easier to use nested MenuItems

```
    <Button Content="Hello">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Level1">
                    <MenuItem Header="Level2">
                        <MenuItem Header="Level3"></MenuItem>
                    </MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me since the styles of the different levels are very different (even though the pictures look alike). I could have expressed it better in the questions, sorry. Popup solves my problem